Chassidic Keter Shem Tov - clarification of origins
The Chassidic sefer Keter Shem Tov is a sefer of the teachings of the Baal Shem Tov.
Does anyone have solid sources to answer any of these general questions about the background of the sefer?

Who wrote it?
When was it redacted?
Who originally published it?
How close to primary are the sources given in answering these questions?


I am curious at how hard it is has been for me to find solid, uncontroversial information about this sefer (and I haven't had time to do substantial research although I do plan to ask my Rav next week bli neder).

When you say write do you mean came up with the teachings or put them in book format? The Torah itself comes from the baal shem tov but similar to the arizal he did not write down his Torah himself but his students did. Rabbi Aharon Hakohen of Apta collected them largely from the written works of Rabbi Yaakov Yosef Hakohen of Polani, a student of the Baal Shem Tov. Is this really controversial?

The one exception within the book is the famous letter written by the baal shem tov himself about how to bring moshiach through the spreading of chassidus

Can you please clarify what you mean with redacted?

I will clarify both: "controversial" means I am finding conflicing information (not political controversy) and "redacted" means compiled and edited for publication (not censored).

I've edited to distinguish this book from the other very famous Keter Shem Tov. http://www.ketershemtob.com/

כתר שם טוב הוא ספר המלקט את דברי תורתו של מייסד תנועת החסידות רבי ישראל בעל שם טוב. את הספר חיבר רבי אהרון הכהן שליקט את הדברים בעיקר מספרי בעל ה'תולדות' רבי יעקב יוסף כ"ץ מפולאנה ספר בן פורת יוסף וספר תולדות יעקב יוסף וספר צפנת פענח. מקורות נוספים לספר מתוך הספר ליקוטים יקרים וספר יושר דברי אמת משולם פֶייבוּש הלוי הֶלֶר מזְבַּרַז.
חלקו הראשון של הספר נדפס בזולקווא בשנת ה'תקנ"ד וחלקו השני נדפס שם בשנת ה'תקנ"ה - https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91_(%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A9%22%D7%98)
